# Django using mod_wsgi for Sub Urls

Tags: django, mod-wsgi, apache-config

Similar questions have been asked before on this site, but I had a doubt as to how my site anchor tags will be replaced when I try to host my website under a suburl.

E.g.
My domain is www.example.com
and my suburl which maps to the Django installation is www.example.com/2010/registration
Now since the anchor tags in my templates (for the links) are of the form of a '/' (to reference the root) succeeded by rest of the url the links are not contained inside www.example.com.
So, for example if my anchor tag is of the form

```
<a href='/profile'>Profile</a>
```

Then my anchor tag on the site becomes www.example.com/profile instead of becoming www.example.com/2010/registration/profile/

Is there any possible way to work around this thing ?

Thanks,
Nitin

Answer (score 2):

There are tags which can be used in templates to ensure correct prefix added. Start by reading:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: What about the HttpResponseRedirect that I have used in the views ? Do i need to replace them with absolute urls manually ?

Comment: @niting: No, you don't need to replace them with absolute URLs. You will be much better off naming your URLs and using `reverse()` instead of absolute URLs.

Answer (score 1):

As Graham says, use the `{% url %}` tag in your templates. In views, use the `reverse()` function, which is equivalent. See [the documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#utility-methods).